# bundler savon installation issues

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, savon

I am installing a local gem called `helper` that has savon listed as dependency in `helper.gemspec`

`s.add_dependency 'savon', '~> 2.3.3'`

When I install `helper` using bundler it throws the following warning

`Could not find gem 'savon (~> 2.3.3) x86-mingw32', which is required by gem
'helper(>= 0) x86-mingw32', in any of the sources.`

I am on Windows 7 with 32-bit ruby.

However, if I install savon independently, it installs fine. What am I doing wrong?
`

Comment: what does it install if you do it independently?

Comment: It installs savon 2.3.3

Comment: but was it the "x86-mingw32" version...anyway maybe ask on the rubyinstaller.org google group?

Comment: The name doesn't have a suffix of that type. How do I check? Thanks

Comment: in gem list it should show like "ffi (1.9.3 x86-mingw32)"

Comment: it seems that bundler or etc, adds the suffix `x86-mingw32`, show please your **Gemfile**, and even before it try to add the line `gem 'savon', '~> 2.0'` into **Gemfile**, and show `bundle install` log here.

Comment: @rogerdpack - When I do a gem install savon independently, gem list shows `savon (2.3.3)`. So no info for platform as you mentioned for ffi above.

Comment: @majioa - my gemfile only contains one gem called `helper` as I mentioned above. This is what leads to the error as it cannot install the savon dependency and throws the error. If I was to put `gem savon` in the Gemfile directly and then run `bundle install` it installs fine. Looks like only when it is in the dependency list in the gemspec of my own gem its got some issues

Comment: which version of *savon* ypu've installed successfully? 2.3.3? or another?

Comment: yep 2.3.3. I have even tried 2.3.0 both install fine

Comment: I wonder if the helper gem somehow accidentally requires the x86-mingw32 version somehow...or maybe it's a bug in rubygems? maybe ask at the ML mentioned previously...